# Как отличить тип UNUserNotification

Tags: ios, swift

Есть метод `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`

Он отрабатывает при клике на `pushNotification`. Можно ли как-то отличить ситуацию когда нажимают на `push` во время когда приложение в `background` и когда приложение выгружено из системы?

Comment: По идее нельзя, сообщения просто регистрируются в общем пуле сообщений и срабатывают по времени. Но можно настроить action и их обрабатывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы узнать состояние приложения можно воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
if state == .background  || state == .inactive {
    // background
} else if state == .active {
    // foreground
}
```

Если приложение было запущено с нажатия на notification, то будет вызван метод 
`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` где в `launchOptions` будет ваше `notification`

Для получения контента `notification` можно сделать примерно следующее:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any]

    if (remoteNotif != nil) {
        // запущено с нотификации
    }

    return true
}
```